# Is There A Text Reducing Tool Via Synonyms?

Tags: synonymy

Is there a tool that can replace text with smaller synonyms, abbreviations, and initialisms?

E.g. "Hello everyone, how are you all doing today? By the way, I'm leaving tonight." could become: "Hi every1, how r yall doin today? Btw, Im leaving 2nite."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are precisely what I was looking for:

- https://tiny.tw/
- https://apps.techglimpse.com/tweetshort/